# Make a column with duplicated values unique in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have a dataframe where a column has duplicate values like

```
employee <- data.frame(name = c('John', 'Joe', 'Mat', 'John', 'Joe'), 
            salary = c(1500, 2000, 1700, 1210, 2100), 
            startdate = c('2012-05-10', '2015-02-17', 
            '2014-09-11', '2011-11-23', '2010-10-27'))
```

I can get the unique elements in column 1 by

```
unique(employee$name)
```

However, I want to make each items in the `name` column unique. If something appears second time append _1 to it. If it appears again append _2 to it. So, in the employee dataframe, I want to change the second column to

```
John
Joe
Mat
John_1
Joe_1
```

Is there a way except looping over it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `make.names` with `unique=TRUE`.  By default, a `.` will be appended before the suffix numbers, and that can be replaced by `_` using `sub`

```
 employee$name <- sub('[.]', '_', make.names(employee$name, unique=TRUE))
```

Or a better option suggested by @DavidArenburg.  If the `name` column is `factor` class, convert the input column to `character` class (`as.character`) before applying the `make.unique`

```
 make.unique(as.character(employee$name), sep = "_")
 #[1] "John"   "Joe"    "Mat"    "John_1" "Joe_1"
```