# add running counter for semi-consecutive strings in vector

Tags: r, count, stringr, find-occurrences

I would like to add a number indicating the x^th occurrence of a word in a vector. (So this question is different from [Make a column with duplicated values unique in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353747/make-a-column-with-duplicated-values-unique-in-a-dataframe) , because I have a simple vector and try to avoid the overhead of casting it to a data.frame).

E.g. for the vector:

```
book, ship, umbrella, book, ship, ship
```

the output would be:

```
book, ship, umbrella, book2, ship2, ship3
```

I have solved this myself by transposing the vector to a dataframe and next using the grouping function. That feels like using a sledgehammer to crack nuts:

```
# add consecutive number for equal string
words <- c("book", "ship", "umbrella", "book", "ship", "ship")

# transpose word vector to data.frame for grouping
df <- data.frame(words = words)
df <- df %>% group_by(words) %>% mutate(seqN = row_number())

# combine columns and remove '1' for first occurrence
wordsVec <- paste0(df$words, df$seqN)       
gsub("1", "", wordsVec)
# [1] "book"     "ship"     "umbrella" "book2"    "ship2"    "ship3"
```

Is there a more clean solution, e.g. using the stringr package?

Comment: You are looking for `make.unique`, i.e. simply `make.unique(words)`

Comment: You don't need to cast it to data frame. If you see my previous comment you will understand. Also, If I do `make.unique(df$v1)`,  **df$v1** is a vector anyway

Comment: You don't need to group. You have a simple vector which makes it much easier to use.

Comment: Hi @sotos make.unique(words), actually does not answer the question: it counts directly consecutive words. E.g. the final ship occurrence should have number 3, not 2, as requested by the OP. `> make.unique(words)
[1] "book"     "ship"     "umbrella" "book.1"   "ship.1"   "ship.2"  `

Comment: Oh so you need them to start counting at the original value

Comment: @Sotos Indeed. Please see the input and output example I provided as well as the 'long' solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still utilize `row_number()` from `dplyr` but you don't need to convert to data frame, i.e.

```
sub('1$', '', ave(words, words, FUN = function(i) paste0(i, row_number(i))))
#[1] "book"     "ship"     "umbrella" "book2"    "ship2"    "ship3"
```

Another option is to use `make.unique` along with `gsubfn` to increment your values by 1, i.e.

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("\\d+", function(x) as.numeric(x) + 1, make.unique(words))
#[1] "book"     "ship"     "umbrella" "book.2"   "ship.2"   "ship.3"
```